# Solution Approach Required for SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server

There are 3 regions - Region1, Region2 and Region3.

For each region there are some unique cities allocated as shown below:

Region1 -> CityA, CityB, CityC
Region2 -> CityG, CityH, CityI
Region3 -> CityK, CityL, CityM

Now i have a set of Teams:
TeamA,TeamB,TeamC...till TeamZ.

Now i have a list (child list) called Team Allocation where the user can fill in the following details:

Team Name: Team A

City Allocated: CityG, CityL (even all available cities can be allocated)

Team Strength: 12

Date: 12/12/2013

The "City Allocated" field should be a lookup in the child list. The user will enter the above details and save the record.

And in another page i will have two dropdowns Regions and Cities and a Fetch button. When i select the City and Region and hit fetch button the respective teams should be displayed.

If I select just the city then the teams of all regions that come under the city should also be filtered. Example: Region1 has CityA, CityB, CityC, so all teams that are allocated to these three cities should also be displayed.

Currently I have this data in excel sheet and needs to be converted into a SharePoint 2013 solution.

Currently I have created the following;

**Region** and **City** in a list (parent list) and 
In child list I have columns like **Team Name**, **City** (from parent list) as lookup, **Team Strength** etc.

How to create a page that will query based on filter conditions Region and City which will get me the team details?

Answer (score 1):

In a previous post, i included a way to do multiple filters in a single page application using REST API and jQuery.  The end result is a form which has two drop downs, which on change filter the results below.  In my case, i'm using an Agent and Month drop down but I'm sure this could be adapted to fit your needs.

[Populating Lookup Field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164205/populating-lookup-field/164333#164333)